# Linux command to return number of bits (32 or 64)?

Tags: linux, command-line, 64-bit, shell, 32-bit

What is a Linux command that I can run to programmatically return either 32 or 64 to indicate whether the processor is a 32 bit or 64 bit processor?

Comment: @Sathya: That's not exactly a duplicate, because the processor can be 64-bit even if the Linux isn't.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- You can see whether the **CPU** is 64-bit, 32-bit, or capable of both by checking the `flags` line in `/proc/cpuinfo`. You have to know the possible flags on your architecture family. For example, on i386/amd64 platforms, the `lm` flag identifies amd64-capable CPUs (CPUs that don't have that flag are i386-only).

  ```
  grep -q '^flags\s*:.*\blm\b' /proc/cpuinfo    # Assuming a PC
  ```
- You can see whether the kernel is 32-bit or 64-bit by querying the architecture with `uname -m`. For example, `i[3456]86` are 32-bit while `x86_64` is 64-bit. Note that on several architectures, a 64-bit kernel can run 32-bit userland programs, so even if the `uname -m` shows a 64-bit kernel, there is no guarantee that 64-bit libraries will be available.

  ```
  [ "$(uname -m)" = "x86_64" ]    # Assuming a PC
  ```

  Note also that `uname -m` may return a “virtualized” value. For example, under Linux, if you run `setarch i386 bash` on an amd64 system, and you run `uname -m` from that bash, you'll see `uname -m` reporting `i386`. This effectively lets you pretend that you're on a “32-bit system” even though the kernel is a 64-bit one, for example to compile 32-bit programs without setting up cross-compilation.
- You can see what is available in userland by querying the [LSB](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/lsb) support with the [`lsb_release`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lsb_release) command. More precisely, `lsb_release -s` prints a `:`-separated list of supported LSB features. Each feature has the form `module-version-architecture`. For example, availability of an ix86 C library is indicated by `core-2.0-ia32`, while `core-2.0-amd64` is the analog for amd64. Not every distribution declares all the available LSB modules though, so more may be available than is detectable in this way.
- You can find out the preferred word size for development (assuming a C compiler is available) by compiling a 5-line C program that prints `sizeof(void*)` or `sizeof(size_t)`.

Comment: On GNU systems (and others if they have it), you should be able to do `getconf WORD_BIT` or `getconf LONG_BIT` instead of having to compile your own C program (trivial, and portable, though it is).

Comment: @Dennis: Thanks for the correction. I hadn't thought of using `getconf` here. It sounds nice in principle, but it's hard to ensure that the results apply to the particular C compiler you'll be using, if there's more than one (typically gcc/icc or similar on Linux, gcc/native cc elsewhere). On a standard system `getconf` should apply to `c89` or `c99` in `$(getconf PATH)`, but in practice I'd worry about someone installing an alternate `cc` which is ran by the vendor `c89` wrapper.

Comment: There is a `.` missing in the regex: `grep '^flags.*:.*\blm\b' /proc/cpuinfo`. Also it only works for me without the `-q` flag

Comment: @byf-ferdy It wasn't a missing `.`: I had “zero or more spaces”, but actually there's a tab. I've changed the regexp to allow tabs as well. With the `-q` flag, there's no output, but the exit status of the command tells you whether the flag is present. If you want output, remove the `-q` flag.

Comment: @Gilles ah I didn't know about the `-q` flag. Ty, works now :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `uname -a` and look for `x86_64` to see if you are running 64-bit. Anything else (As far as I know) and you are running 32-bit or you are on non-PC hardware such as `alpha`, `sparc`, or `ppc64`.

Comment: Anything else and you're running 32-bit, or non-PC hardware (such as `alpha`, `sparc64`, `ppc64`, ...

Comment: @Gilles: Thanks, I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

```
uname -m | sed 's/x86_//;s/i[3-6]86/32/'
```

Answer (score 2):

*getconf* uses the fewest system calls:

```
$ strace getconf LONG_BIT | wc -l
253

$ strace arch | wc -l
280

$ strace uname -m | wc -l
281

$ strace grep -q lm /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l
301
```

Answer (score 1):

Type:

```
uname -a
```

If you get `x86_64 GNU/Linux` you're running a 64 bit kernel. If you get something similar to `i386/i486/i586/i686` you're most probably running a 32 bit kernel

Comment: That's not the question.